# stuck in maintenance mode - unable to log into admin panel

Tags: admin-panel, backup, maintenance

While preforming a backup, I got hung up and had to refresh page (after an hour) "Put the site in maintenance mode" was checked. Now my admin log in is redirecting to the site itself. I deleted maintenance.flag through ftp but I'm still unable to log into my admin panel. I added some "allow IP code" to my index.php file but again, no go. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Magento root folder for a file called maintenance.flag and rename or delete it. You should then be out of maintenace mode

Comment: I did that first - it must not have worked because I still can't log into admin panel. Also, I added some "allow IP" code to index.php without success.

Comment: have you tried taking a fresh index.php file and lobbing in that? (rename/backup you current index.php file)

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the index.php with a fresh file - still locked out.

Answer (score 1):

If you get redirected to the site, but *not* to the installer *and* you don't get a 503 maintenance mode page, then your admin URL has changed. Look in your `local.xml`.

If you get the 503 template and IP exceptions don't help, check for an alternate maintenance mode extension (BalkeTechnologies StoreMaintenance is one I frequently see). Another possibility is that there's a reverse proxy in the chain and it's hard-caching error messages. In that case request the admin with a query string, triggering a refresh (normally).

Finally, Redis_Session module also throws a 503 if it can't connect to Redis.

Answer (score -2):

Deleted the maintenance.flag file and the site is back to normal.